# Why does opening Blender cause the CMD window to open?

Tags: error

For some reason, everytime I open Blender, CMD opens, displays "`Read prefs: C:\Users\(my name)\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.3\config\usepref.blend`, and just sits there. I haven't done anything, but all it does is take Blender with it when it closes. Anyone else having this problem?

Comment: The cmd windows opens on startup in all the years and all versions since I've been using Blender, this is absolutely normal. But usually it closes automatically after Blender's UI is running... it just closes Blender if I close the cmd window before the startup is finished.

Comment: You could temporary rename the Blender Foundation folder in the appdata folder and have a look if the problem persists. The cmd window should definitely not stay open at startup. That smells like a bug. But please test the newest Blender version before you report it. 3.3 is already one version behind ...

Comment: Tried both, only worked for first session.